# How to retrieve element in array by comparing its member value

Tags: php

I have an array of Objects that have a member `name`.

How can I find the first object which fulfills the condition

```
Object->name == "foo"
```

In practice, is there a faster way than:

```
$needle = null;
foreach($myarray as $myobject)
{
    if($myobject->name == "foo")
    {
        $needle = $myobject;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's as fast as you can achieve, although if the name is available directly then calling an access method could be optimized out.

Comment: I'll edit it, thx for the comment.

Comment: @SPlatten Using `array_search()` should be more optimized because the loop is made internally and avoid a copy of object's reference caused by `foreach`.